# How to plot an image as a plane in a 3D plot in Julia

Tags: plot, 3d, julia

This is my first question on stackoverflow so constructive criticism on how to pose questions and how to be a productive member of this site is appreciated.

I have a 3D plot of a building with floor outlines, a line plot of a track in the building and the location of wifi beacons as a scatter plot. The plot is made using Plots.jl with the gr backend. Now, I want to overlay each floor with a floor plan image. I have the floor plans as png:s and want to plot them each as planes in the 3D image, preferably using the gr backend so I don't have to change anything.

So far I have been unable to find a way to plot RGB arrays with any kind of z-component, the result is always flat. It would be very much appreciated if some one could point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance